# Facebook Open Graph doesnt update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

Hy!

Can someone say me if it's possible to force facebook to do a new scan for each new "ajax"-url any person adds. I wanna link user-profiles from our car-club, but .. see ..

To begin from the first point:

> 0) I have this URL:

User-Url: https://XXXXX-carclub.at/#!/facebook

> 1) Pass Open-Graph Request in index.php with:

```
 if (preg_match("/facebookexternalhit/is", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        include("./includes/opengraph/facebook.php");
        exit();
    }
```

> 2) Give this output to the Crawler: (With body, etc.)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
<title>XXXXXXAustria - OpenGraph</title>
<!-- Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Audi A4, 2.5 TDI Quattro von Christoph Eder" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXX"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="XXXXXX"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://url.at/#!/facebook" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://url.at/images/membercars/1_1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="XXXXXX-Carclub.at" />
<meta property="og:description" content="16'' Stahlfelgen, Audi Originalfahrwerk, ..." />
</head>
```

> 3) Start open-graph debugger and got this result:

[image: OpenGraph Debugger Output]

> 4) Put URL into status-update, got preview with text from the start-page:

[image: Facebook Statusupdate-Preview]

> 5) Finally, in the update(post) i have this result, with the right text but wrong image..

[image: Status result, wrong image]

Comment: You can trigger a re-scrape (or an initial one, for as of yet unshared objects) via API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Maybe you should also let `Facebot` through. Have you had a look at you logs? Which User-Agent etc. is shown for the FB requests?

Comment: "facebookexternalhit" is the only user-tag i see.
but i let "Facebot" through to be sure.

Thx 4 answer!